# Is it possible to disable editing layout in Android Studio preview window?

Tags: android, android-studio

When you use preview layout in Android Studio, you can edit the layout with mouse in preview.

I only create layout with XML but I use preview to jump to the correct section of the XML. However,  all the editing features are easily misclick.

For example, when I click on a `ImageView`, I accidentally delete my all my constraint for `ConstraintLayout` of the `ImageView` which is very annoying.

So, is it possible to disable editing layout in Android Studio preview window?

Comment: You can stop using the preview directly. Open the XML section, then select the preview option from right pane. You will be able to see xml changes immediately and you won't need to use mouse actions.

Comment: just use whatever version control tool, which gives you unlimited undo. besides, Android Studio also features a "local history", which can also be used to revert the latest changes.

Comment: @Toaster When you have  hundreds of line in an XML, you need to navigate to correct XML section.

Comment: @MartinZeitler  You don't commit every time you change a line right? Also, sometime the GUI edit does not generate error which is  hard to catch but result in bugs later on.

Comment: @Joshua that's what the "local history" is good for. and if you have hundreds of lines of XML; maybe consider splitting it and use `include`, which can vastly reduce copy & paste.

Comment: @Joshua Whatever xml element you select, AS will put a blue margin on it, in preview.

Comment: @Toaster I knew that. But what I want is navigation. I want to click through preview and go to code. Not scroll through the entire XML.

Comment: @Joshua I don't think there will be an option to disable the UI Editor. As you're facing problems, you have to do that unless it's fixed. You can try reimporting the project into AS after giving a full clean start with AS. :-D :-D

Comment: Use the structure treeview on the left of preview to navigate